# Why do I need to specify multiple types of binding flag to get info on a single field?

Tags: c#, reflection

When trying to get field information using reflection, I need to use the code

```
SomeObject.GetType().GetField(
    "FieldName",
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
```

In particular, I must specify both `BindingFlags.NonPublic` **and** `BindingFlags.Instance`. If I only specify one, I get a null return.

If I am only looking at a single field, why do I need to specify multiple binding flag types?

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with field count you want to get. You have to do the same when you use GetField(s) method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These flags play a role of some sort of a filter.

If you omit `BindingFlags.NonPublic`, `GetField()` function does not look for `private`, `internal` and `protected` fields.

And you have to specify either `BindingFlags.Instance` or `BindingFlags.Static` to define what you are looking for.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc.aspx:

> You must specify either **BindingFlags.Instance** or **BindingFlags.Static** in order to get a return.
>
> ...
>
> Specify **BindingFlags.NonPublic** to include non-public fields (that is, private, internal, and protected fields) in the search. Only protected and internal fields on base classes are returned; private fields on base classes are not returned.

Comment: I was treating the expression as if it was a boolean or. This makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

It's how the search is implemented. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (in the `Note` section):

> You must specify Instance or Static along with Public or NonPublic or
>   no members will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

every `BindingFlag` has a meaning

flags do not specify how many fields you'll receive but what kind of field `GetField` method should look for

for example if you do not specify `NonPublic` then you may not be able to retrieve any private, protected or internal fields

in your case

- NonPublic - your desired property is not public
- Instance - your desired field is an instance field not a static field

other common flags

- DeclaredOnly - which are declared in the class, not inherited one
- FlattenHierarchy - it will look into every base class for the given name
- IgnoreCase - as implies ignored the casing of the name
- Public - looks for public members
- Static - looks for static members

more on [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags)

Answer (score 1):

The flags form a filter. They define the types of fields returned. If your field is not public and is an instance field (i.e. is not a static field), you need to include these flags.

You could as well specify additional flags like `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static` in order to include other filed types.

Answer (score 1):

if it is going about: `System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance` - from msdn:

> You must specify either BindingFlags.Instance or BindingFlags.Static
>   in order to get a return.

[(source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

That flag is required to determine wheter you want to get Static or Non-Static members (or both).

Next `System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic` tells, that you want to get non-public member (that by default are not visible outside class). Fields are usually private that is why probably you get `null` when trying to retreive field without `BindingFlags.Public`.